# How to assign event handlers to custom elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom-events

Say I have a Vue component `Checkbox.vue` with the following content.

```
<template>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
        <label for="checkbox">Label</label>
    </div>
</template>
```

How can I add an event listener to it from another component to trigger a method to get its value like so

```
//App.vue

<template>
    <checkbox @input="someMethod"></checkbox>
</template>

import Checkbox from 'checkbox';    
export default{
    components: {
        'checkbox': Checkbox
    },

    methods: {
        someMethod(){
            console.log(GET CHECKBOX VALUE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to be called when the value changes? You could use a watcher for that

Comment: Not necessarily its value change, I'd like to have the ability to assign any event, say `click` for instance.

Comment: something like v-on:click ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$emit`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) to trigger the event:

`Checkbox.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" @change="$emit('change', $event.target.checked)">
        <label for="checkbox">Label</label>
    </div>
</template>
```

This allows you to trigger any event you want. The event handler in the parent component will be called whenever it's emitted.  In this case the event handler will receive an argument containing the checkbox's `checked` value (boolean).

Answer (score 4):

```
<div class="checkbox">
     <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" @click="onClickMe">
     <label for="checkbox">Label</label> 
</div>

methods: {
    onClickMe() {
        this.$emit('child-say','hello');
    } 
}



App.vue
    <Checkbox v-on:child-say="someMethod" />

methods: {
    someMethod(data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
}
```